# Expected primary expression befor "input"

Tags: c++

I want to "quick sort" the array that I have read from a `.txt` file; but the code is generating an error. It says `"Expected primary expression before "input" "`.

Any help is appreciated. This is the code. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void quickSort(int tabele[], int majtas, int djathtas){
    if(majtas<djathtas){
        int vendPivot = ndarja(tabele, majtas, djathtas);
        /* rendit sipas rradhes elementet para dhe pas vendPivot */
        quickSort(tabele, majtas,vendPivot-1);
        quickSort(tabele,vendPivot+1, djathtas);
    }

}    
vector<int> lexoTabele(){
    vector<int> data;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("detyraekursit.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    int x;

    cout<<"Vektori INPUT para renditjes ";
    while (inFile >> x) {
        data.push_back(x);
    }
    inFile.close();

    return data;
}

int main() {  
    vector<int> input = lexoTabele();
    int x,y;
    for(int i = 0;i < input.size();i++) {
        cout<< i << ", " << input[i];
    }
    quickSort(vector<int>input,x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and what constitutes a [mcve].

Comment: `quickSort(vector<int>input,x,y);` appears to be trying to define a variable inside a function call. I recommend consulting your text on how to do this correctly.